# tinymce adding br tags after li and p tags

Tags: html, tinymce, umbraco

I have an RTE in umbraco which has the following markup

```
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nisl sonet mnesarchum vis ex, nec quas posse assueverit an. Eam an doming docendi, et mundi eripuit vim. An nisl tota imperdiet usu. Mazim aeque instructior quo ad, ex cum debet mundi, in omittam dignissim sed. An cum summo lucilius oportere, copiosae vituperata definitiones has id. Vis sale mucius id, duo enim definitionem ne.</strong></p>
    <p>Quem meis pro ne. Has et brute denique. At mei maiorum similique enter code herevoluptatibus, saepe efficiendi ullamcorper qui ne. Admodum detraxit interesset at usu, ei mea admodum fuisset petentium, numquam accumsan conceptam ne sea.</p>
    <ul>
    <li><span>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem </span></li>
    <li><span>Accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem </span></li>
    <li><span>Aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi </span></li>
    <li><span>Architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt <a data-id="2831" href="/{localLink:2831}" target="_blank" title="United Kingdom">explicabo</a></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="umb-loader" style="height: 10px; margin: 10px 0px;"></div>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><iframe width="615" height="346" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScMzIvxBSi4?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
```

but when it outputs on to the screen it adds 
 tags like the following

```
                    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nisl sonet mnesarchum vis ex, nec quas posse assueverit an. Eam an doming docendi, et mundi eripuit vim. An nisl tota im`enter code here`perdiet usu. Mazim aeque instructior quo ad, ex cum debet mundi, in omittam dignissim sed. An cum summo lucilius oportere, copiosae vituperata definitiones has id. Vis sale mucius id, duo enim definitionem ne.</strong></p><br>
<p>Quem meis pro ne. Has et brute denique. At mei maiorum similique voluptatibus, saepe efficiendi ullamcorper qui ne. Admodum detraxit interesset at usu, ei mea admodum fuisset petentium, numquam accumsan conceptam ne sea.</p><br>
<ul><br>
<li><span>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem </span></li><br>
<li><span>Accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem </span></li><br>
<li><span>Aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi </span></li><br>
<li><span>Architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt <a data-id="2831" href="/united-kingdom/" target="_blank" title="United Kingdom">explicabo</a></span></li><br>
</ul><br>
```

Any ideas how I can stop it doing this?

Thanks in advance

**Update** added tinymce config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Any changes to this file requires the application (umbraco) to restart -->
<!-- This can be done by touching the web.config or recycling the application pool -->
<tinymceConfig>
  <commands>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>code</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Code</name>
      <icon>images/editor/code.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="code">code</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>1</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>codemirror</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Code mirror</name>
      <icon>images/editor/code.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="codemirror">codemirror</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>1</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>removeformat</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Remove format</name>
      <icon>images/editor/removeformat.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="removeformat">removeformat</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>2</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>undo</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Undo</name>
      <name>Remove Format</name>
      <icon>images/editor/undo.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="undo">undo</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>11</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>redo</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Redo</name>
      <icon>images/editor/redo.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="redo">redo</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>12</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>cut</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Cut</name>
      <icon>images/editor/cut.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="cut">cut</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>13</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>copy</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Copy</name>
      <icon>images/editor/copy.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="copy">copy</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>14</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>paste</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Paste</name>
      <icon>images/editor/paste.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="paste">paste</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>15</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>styleselect</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Style select</name>
      <icon>images/editor/showStyles.png</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="styleselect">styleselect</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>20</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>bold</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Bold</name>
      <icon>images/editor/bold.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="bold">bold</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>21</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>italic</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Italic</name>
      <icon>images/editor/italic.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="italic">italic</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>22</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>underline</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Underline</name>
      <icon>images/editor/underline.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="underline">underline</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>23</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>strikethrough</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Strikethrough</name>
      <icon>images/editor/strikethrough.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="strikethrough">strikethrough</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>24</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>justifyleft</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Justify left</name>
      <icon>images/editor/justifyleft.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="alignleft">justifyleft</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>31</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>justifycenter</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Justify center</name>
      <icon>images/editor/justifycenter.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="aligncenter">justifycenter</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>32</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>justifyright</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Justify right</name>
      <icon>images/editor/justifyright.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="alignright">justifyright</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>33</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>justifyfull</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Justify full</name>
      <icon>images/editor/justifyfull.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="alignjustify">alignjustify</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>34</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>bullist</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Bullet list</name>
      <icon>images/editor/bullist.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="bullist">bullist</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>41</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>numlist</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Numbered list</name>
      <icon>images/editor/numlist.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="numlist">numlist</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>42</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>outdent</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Decrease indent</name>
      <icon>images/editor/outdent.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="outdent">outdent</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>43</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>indent</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Increase indent</name>
      <icon>images/editor/indent.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="indent">indent</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>44</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>mceLink</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Insert/edit link</name>
      <icon>images/editor/link.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="true" frontendCommand="link">link</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>51</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>unlink</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Remove link</name>
      <icon>images/editor/unLink.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="unlink">unlink</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>52</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>mceInsertAnchor</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Anchor</name>
      <icon>images/editor/anchor.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="anchor">anchor</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>53</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>mceImage</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Image</name>
      <icon>images/editor/image.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="true" frontendCommand="umbmediapicker">image</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>61</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>umbracomacro</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Macro</name>
      <icon>images/editor/insMacro.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="true" frontendCommand="umbmacro">umbracomacro</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>62</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>mceInsertTable</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Table</name>
      <icon>images/editor/table.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="true" frontendCommand="table">table</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>63</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>umbracoembed</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Embed</name>
      <icon>images/editor/media.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="true" frontendCommand="umbembeddialog">umbracoembed</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>66</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>inserthorizontalrule</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Horizontal rule</name>
      <icon>images/editor/hr.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="hr">hr</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>71</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>subscript</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Subscript</name>
      <icon>images/editor/sub.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="subscript">subscript</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>72</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>superscript</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Superscript</name>
      <icon>images/editor/sup.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="superscript">superscript</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>73</priority>
    </command>
    <command>
      <umbracoAlias>mceCharMap</umbracoAlias>
      <name>Character map</name>
      <icon>images/editor/charmap.gif</icon>
      <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="false" frontendCommand="charmap">charmap</tinyMceCommand>
      <priority>74</priority>
    </command>
  </commands>
  <plugins>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">code</plugin>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">codemirror</plugin>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">paste</plugin>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">umbracolink</plugin>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">anchor</plugin>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">charmap</plugin>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">table</plugin>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">lists</plugin>
    <plugin loadOnFrontend="true">hr</plugin>
  </plugins>
  <validElements>
    <![CDATA[+a[id|style|rel|data-id|rev|charset|hreflang|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur|onclick|
ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup],-strong/-b[class|style],-em/-i[class|style],
-strike[class|style],-u[class|style],#p[id|style|dir|class|align],-ol[class|reversed|start|style|type],-ul[class|style],-li[class|style],br[class],
img[id|dir|lang|longdesc|usemap|style|class|src|onmouseover|onmouseout|border|alt=|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|umbracoorgwidth|umbracoorgheight|onresize|onresizestart|onresizeend|rel|data-id],
-sub[style|class],-sup[style|class],-blockquote[dir|style|class],-table[border=0|cellspacing|cellpadding|width|height|class|align|summary|style|dir|id|lang|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],
-enter code heretr[id|lang|dir|class|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],tbody[id|class],
thead[id|class],tfoot[id|class],#td[id|lang|dir|class|colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|bgcolor|background|bordercolor|scope],
-th[id|lang|dir|class|colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|scope],caption[id|lang|dir|class|style],-div[id|dir|class|align|style],
-span[class|align|style],-pre[class|align|style],address[class|align|style],-h1[id|dir|class|align|style],-h2[id|dir|class|align|style],
-h3[id|dir|class|align|style],-h4[id|dir|class|align|style],-h5[id|dir|class|align|style],-h6[id|style|dir|class|align|style],hr[class|style],
dd[id|class|title|style|dir|lang],dl[id|class|title|style|dir|lang],dt[id|class|title|style|dir|lang],object[class|id|width|height|codebase|*],
param[name|value|_value|class],embed[type|width|height|src|class|*],map[name|class],area[shape|coords|href|alt|target|class],bdo[class],button[class],iframe[*]]]>
  </validElements>
  <invalidElements>font</invalidElements>

  <!-- this area is for custom config settings that should be added during TinyMCE initialization -->
  <customConfig>
    <!--    <config key="myKey">mySetting</config>-->
    <config key="entity_encoding">raw</config>
    <config key="codemirror">
      {
      "indentOnInit": false,
      "path": "../../../../lib/codemirror",
      "config": {
      },
      "jsFiles": [
      ],
      "cssFiles": [
      ]
      }
    </config>
  </customConfig>
</tinymceConfig>
```

Comment: How are you rendering the RTE content in the view? Is there anything that might replacing line break characters ("\r\n" or "\n") with <br> tags?

Comment: I rended it using a  @Html.Raw(viewModel.Content)

Comment: which version of Umbraco you're using?

Comment: The current version is 7.5.2

Comment: Can you add your tinyMceConfig.config file. You can find it in the "Config" folder.

Comment: @CraigMayers updated

Comment: @Marty had to add an Answer to add the image.

Answer (score 0):

@Marty your file has 1 difference compared to mine. See the image attached.
Remove the text "enter code here" and try again OR download that file again.

Please also ensure you recycle your AppPool to make sure it pulls in the config changes.[image]